# How to delete row in data frame based on value in set?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete the row in my data frame if it meets any value in a set. I have tried many different iterations of the following code, but they don't work:

```
if subid in intersection == df_1["SubId"][x]:
    for x in range(len(df_1)):
        del df_1.iloc[x]
```

I am getting Key Error:0. Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have defined intersection as the following:

```
intersection = set(ABC).intersection(XYZ)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to remove those then use `isin`:

```
df_1[~df_1["SubId"].isin(intersection)]
```

This will produce a boolean mask of the rows where they match one of the values in `intersection` and we invert the mask using `~`

What you're doing will be slow plus won't your indexing potentially run off the end of the df if you keep removing rows?

Example:

```
In [2]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,4], 'b':np.random.randn(5)})
df
Out[2]:
   a         b
0  0  0.987283
1  1  0.683479
2  2  1.640774
3  3  1.262665
4  4 -1.462040
In [3]:

df[~df.a.isin([0,3])]
Out[3]:
   a         b
1  1  0.683479
2  2  1.640774
4  4 -1.462040
```

Comment: Doesn't this just remove elements from the DataFrame, as opposed to the entire row? I'm getting a correct solution as `df.ix[~df.isin(intersection).apply(lambda x: x.any(), axis=1)]`

Comment: No, I'm filtering the entire df based on whether a series doesn't have that value, it'll return a boolean series that can be used to mask the entire df

Comment: @JamesKelleher  Also calling `apply` should be the last resort when working with arrays, it is not vectorised and therefore will not scale well

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working. Should I re-index to fix the index or is there a better way to remove rows?

Comment: You'll have to define not working, also you need to post representable raw input data and code to reproduce your data and errors

Comment: Sorry, let me re-phrase it: I can remove the rows but is there a better way to do this to preserve the index?

Comment: You could reset the index and drop the rows and set the index again, but the index should still be preserved, my example shows that the index values are preserved, you'll have to post data, code, desired output and errors giving feedback using comments is not that informative